# Api is returning unexpected data in bestbuy

Tags: best-buy-api

I am trying to get the iphone5 search .

This is the url which I am hitting .

[http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(search=Iphone5)?apiKey=myapi&page=1](http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products%28search=Iphone5%29?apiKey=myapi&page=1)

And this response is completely different to what I am expecting .I am  looking for the same data as what I got after searching the Iphone  at bestbuy.com user interface .

My  response contains some headphone details which is not Iphone .

May I know Y it is so .What other parameters I need to pass to get the correct data .

Please help me out .

UPdate :
  It shows only accessories  data instead of Iphone5 product details .

Answer (score 1):

The API's search currently uses a different relevancy model than bestbuy.com's search. If you're specifically looking for iPhones, then you'd probably want to filter based on category as well. You might also want to change your query to search by 'name' for even more specificity.

A URL that worked for me:

[http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="iPhone*"&categoryPath.id=pcmcat209400050001)?format=json&apiKey=YourAPIKey](http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products%28name=%22iPhone%2a%22&categoryPath.id=pcmcat209400050001%29?format=json&apiKey=YourAPIKey)

If you wanted to limit your results to the iPhone 5, 5c, or 5s, a better query would be:

[http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="iPhone 5*"&categoryPath.id=pcmcat209400050001)?format=json&apiKey=YourAPIKey](http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products%28name=%22iPhone%205%2a%22&categoryPath.id=pcmcat209400050001%29?format=json&apiKey=YourAPIKey)

We have more extensive documentation on our different search options on our new developer site at https://developer.bestbuy.com/documentation. Make sure to check there if there's anything fancier you need to do!